# How can I change Android app background image when phone is tilted?

Tags: android, image, background

I´ve made an app where´s just some text and a background image. 
When I tilt my phone my background image gets streched out.. 
What I want to do is when I tilt the phone I get now background image.

Comment: Do you want a different background image for landscape mode?

Comment: Is your question answered?

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is create different layouts for your views in landscape and portrait mode and put the landscape ones in res/layout-land and the portrait ones in res/layout-port. Simply get your current XML file and copy it into both the portrait and landscape stalks and then just change the drawable that is referenced for the background. That way you can have one that fits well for portrait and another that you've edited to fit for landscape views.

Answer (score 0):

you need to provide a different layout for that orientation.
create a layout-landscape folder, and in that layout change the background to the one you want for your landscape layout. besides you can completely customize your landscape orientation that way.

Answer (score 0):

yes you can change the background
for that you have to create another xml file with same name of the xml you are using right now
then copy all the code from your previous xml to this new xml
you have to create this xml inside the land named folder,if that folder dosent exist than crete a folder name land inside your layout folder..
you just have to change one thing in your xml and here you gooo

```
 android:background="@drawable/yournewbackgroundname"
```

do not change any thing in our old xml